# What PHP function converts ø into &Aring;?

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what PHP function converts `ø` into `&Aring;`?

I'm storing special characters like `æ, ø, å, ö, ä` to html encoded characters.

I've search google and Stackoverflow, but can't figure out what to seach for.
I've managed it before, but can't remember how :(

The following is not working:

```
$tmp = ('Øving, ære, blå');
$tmp2 = htmlspecialchars($tmp);
echo $tmp.' - '.$tmp2;
```

The output is: `Øving, ære, blå - Øving, ære, blå`

I'ev also tried `htmlentities`:

```
$tmp = ('Øving, ære, blå');
$tmp2 = htmlentities($tmp);
echo $tmp.' - '.$tmp2;
```

This outputs: `Øving, ære, blå - Ã�ving, Ã¦re, blÃ¥`

when I want it to be
`Øving, ære, blå - &Oslash;ving, &aelig;re, bl&aring;`

Comment: Ah, so you don't want this for HTML like you specified after all.  Got it.

Comment: I am using this in HTML. Only HTML does not include charecters like `æ, ø or å`. That is why I must use encoding like `&Oslash;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the encoding in which your special characters are encoded (inside php).
Assuming UTF-8 you can do

```
 $str2 =  htmlentities($str2,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
```

but the following might be more robust, (if you have support for mb_ functions)

```
$str2 =  mb_convert_encoding ($str1,"HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8");
```

Update: I've verified that both work, in the specified example (character u+00C5). And that the second is indeed more robust in the following sense: when a named entity is not found for the given unicode character, the first alternative leaves it intact, the second uses the numeric entity. If we want to avoid non-ascii chars in HTML pages, the second is to be preferred, then. Some lines to check:

```
<?php 

 for($i=129;$i<3000;$i++)
    printUnicode($i);

  function printUnicode($value) {
      $one_character = pack("L", $value);
      $u8 = iconv("UTF-32", "UTF-8", $one_character);
      echo join("\t",array(
         $value,
         $u8,
         htmlentities($u8,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8"),
         mb_convert_encoding($u8,"HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8")))
            . "\n";

  }
?>
```

And some example output:

```
187     »       &raquo;         &raquo;
188     ¼       &frac14;        &frac14;
189     ½       &frac12;        &frac12;
190     ¾       &frac34;        &frac34;
191     ¿       &iquest;        &iquest;
192     À       &Agrave;        &Agrave;
193     Á       &Aacute;        &Aacute;
194     Â       &Acirc;         &Acirc;
195     Ã       &Atilde;        &Atilde;
196     Ä       &Auml;          &Auml;
197     Å       &Aring;         &Aring;
...
655     ʏ       ʏ              &#655;
656     ʐ       ʐ              &#656;
657     ʑ       ʑ              &#657;
658     ʒ       ʒ              &#658;
659     ʓ       ʓ              &#659;
```

Comment: humm... I've tried your solution, both of them, but it still outputs `Øving, ære, blå`. I'll have to check this tomorrow and see what I can come up with.

Comment: See Paul's comment in his answer. Apparently you are failing to understand that strings in PHP are just a bunch of bytes, you must be aware of the encoding you are using inside PHP (no necesarily related to you HTML charset)

Comment: Yeah. I don't quite grasp the encoding thingy. I'll test some more the next few days. And yes, `&oslash;` - typo.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be more appropriate: [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Why would that be more appropriate?  That will attempt to convert everything (everything with an entity).  If he only needs it when he needs it, then `htmlspecialchars()` will work.  Unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: Ah, I see now.  He clarified his question... I guess he isn't actually using this in HTML.

Comment: @Briedis- That's what I though too. But as you can see from my update, I'm not quite getting the desired output. I'm using HTML5, so my `DOCTYPE` is just `HTML`and meta tag `charset` is set to `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$tmp = ('Øving, ære, blå');
$tmp2 = htmlentities($tmp, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo $tmp.' - '.$tmp2;
```

From a command line, I get the intended string:

`&Oslash;ving, &aelig;re, bl&aring;`

Comment: How is your source file encoded? However it is encoded, try changing the third parameter in the `htmlentities()` call.

Comment: I'm using HTML5, so my DOCTYPE is just HTMLand meta tag charset is set to utf-8.

Comment: That is to instruct the browser to what encoding it should use to read the output. `htmlentities` can have different effects based on the source file's encoding. If you are unsure on your source file's encoding and are using Windows, you can try Notepad++ where you can change the encoding. You could also try `htmlentities($tmp, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO8859-1');` as it is another common encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do:

```
$tmp = str_replace(array('æ','ø','å'),array('&Oslash;','&aelig;','&aring;'),$tmp);
```

Comment: I could, but it could be other characters like `é, è, ë, ê, É,` etc. So I don't want to make a large list.